# Spring Batch with active profile still looks for Application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am having trouble getting profiles to work in Spring Boot.

To start with, I would like to have a profile named `local`.

[image: IntelliJ Spring Boot Settings]

As I understand it, specifying `spring.profiles.active=local` (or setting the Active Profile in IntelliJ's run/debug configuration) should tell Spring Boot to look for a file named **`Application-local.properties`**.

After moving **`Application.properties`** to **`Application-local.properties`** and running the application, I get

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

So it is still looking for the default **`Application.properties`**. Is there anything else I need to specify? This seems like something that should be super simple but has had me stuck for a couple days now.

Comment: AFAIK you only have one `application.properties` but you can define multiple profiles inside. I have a spring boot project with `local`, `development` and `production` profiles all inside one `application.yml` file

Comment: @hughjdavey `.properties` files cannot have multiple profiles embedded, only `.yml` files can do that. For `.properties` files, profiles are done using different files named `application-{profile}.properties`. That actually also applies to YAML files: `application-{profile}.yml`. With YAML you can do it either way.

Comment: @Andreas my mistake thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.properties` is the base property file and will always be loaded. Profiles allow loading *additional* files.

If you don't want any common properties, leave the file blank.

See [24.4 Profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties):

> In **addition to** `application.properties` files, profile-specific properties can also be defined using the naming convention `application-{profile}.properties`.

Comment: It appears also that, at least the additional `application-{profile}.properties` files are case sensitive. The project I inherited is using a capital `Application.properties` file which seems to work, (although there may be some custom code I don't know about supporting that). The profiles are working after switching to lower case.

Comment: @bdetweiler That would depend on your OS. Windows file names are case-insensitive, but Linux file names are case-sensitive. When you package the app into a jar file, the jar file is case-sensitive, I believe, but running the app from your IDE on Windows would not be.

Comment: Oh good point. Developing on Windows, deploying to Linux, so the case will  matter.